# regular expression keep one or zero with regexpall

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to convert some text to something else with replaceall and regular expressions.

My text is like the following:

```
This is with something extra constraint xhiho,

This is without something extra constraint hfdlh
```

Now what I want as result is the following:

```
This is with something extra, --constraint xhiho

This is without something extra -- constraint hfdlh
```

So I need to put 2 `-` before the word constraint and if there is a `,` at the end put it in front of the 2 `-`

I tried with the following piece of code:

```
oConvert = oConvert.replaceAll("constraint(.*)(,?)", "$2--constraint$1");
```

But it is not working, it does not give the `,` in front of the 2 `-`

Comment: Use `constraint([^,]*)(,?)` or `constraint(.*[^,])(,?)`

Comment: Both don't work

Comment: Try `oConvert = oConvert.replaceAll("(?m)(\\s*)constraint([^,]*)(,?)$", "$3$1--constraint$2");`

Comment: does it also for the line where no , is

Comment: But you asked exactly for that. `This is without something extra constraint hfdlh` must become `This is without something extra -- constraint hfdlh`

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\h+constraint\\h+[^,]*)(,?)", "$2 --$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jjHC5N/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
  - `constraint`: Match `constraint`
  - `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
  - `[^,]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `,`
- `)`: End of capture group #1
- `(`: Start of capture group #2

  - `,?`: Match an optional comma
- `)`: End of capture group #2

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't put the , in front of the --

Comment: There will be a `,` before `--`. Did you check output in linked demo: https://regex101.com/r/jjHC5N/1/

Comment: Note that if trailing comma is not at then end then `$` will not be matched and you should use: `(\\h+constraint\\h+[^,]*)(,?)` as regex.

Comment: After the comma are spaces, so the second option is better, but it also puts a , in front of the -- where it shouldn't be

Comment: But you wanted to put `,` before `--` if there is a comma in the end. Can you check output in https://regex101.com/r/jjHC5N/2 and let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: If I check on the website this works, but if I use it in my java program with replaceAll it does not. I did a copy paste of my code in the website and it worked. But in java with the same copy past it did not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213938/discussion-between-anubhava-and-nightfox79).